# How to move from a View to a Tab Bar Controller in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm very new to iOS and I have an issue.

I have a view with a login form and a button.

I want to make it so that once the button is pressed, the login is processed and if successful it loads the first tab of a Tab Bar Controller.

How do I do this? I've tried creating a manual segue and loading it but that doesn't work :(

Here is my code for what happens after login (Its a GitHub login form):

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
Boolean error = NO;
NSString* username = _usernameField.text;
NSString* password = _passwordField.text;
UIColor *red = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
UIColor *black = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:0/255.0f blue:0/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
GitHub* github = [[GitHub alloc] init];
bool result = NO;

// Checking for blanks
if([username isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [_usernameLabel setTextColor:red];
    error = YES;
}
else
{
    [_usernameLabel setTextColor:black];
}

if([password isEqualToString:@""])
{
    [_passwordLabel setTextColor:red];
    error = YES;
}
else
{
    [_passwordLabel setTextColor:black];
}

if(!error)
{
    result = [github loginWithUsername:username AndPassword:password];
    if(result == YES)
    {
        // Logged in successfully!
        [_errorLabel setHidden:YES];

        NSLog(@"YEP");

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        // Error Handling
        [_errorLabel setText:@"Error: Incorrect Username / Password"];
        [_errorLabel setHidden:NO];
        [_passwordField setText:@""];
    }
}
else
{
    // Error Handling
    [_errorLabel setText:@"Error: Please correct errors below:"];
    [_errorLabel setHidden:NO];
    [_passwordField setText:@""];
}
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error that you get when performSegueWithIdentifier is executed? Or what specific problem do you see? "Doesn't work" is a bit broad. :)

Comment: Well, I get no error and the performSegueWithIdentifier is never run.

Comment: The login is correct and the line `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];` does get run.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? Are both your original and your target view controllers instantiated from the storyboard? (you don't have to instantiate them yourself, but if you instantiate them yourself, you have to make sure that you instantiate them from the storyboard)

Comment: Yeah I'm using 1 storyboard. Here's my storyboard: http://cl.ly/OsP3

Comment: Try linking your manual segue to the tab bar controller. Also, it looks like a push segue. You most likely need a navigation controller to perform a push segue. Are you sure you don't get any warnings in the console when performSegueWithIdentifier is executed?

Comment: (not sure about the push segue tbh, hard to see behind the screenshot)

Comment: Tried this and there are no warnings and nothing gets loaded at all :/